# Scala inherit parameterized constructor

Tags: scala, inheritance, constructor

I have an abstract base class with several optional parameters:

```
abstract case class Hypothesis(
    requirement: Boolean = false,
    onlyDays:   Seq[Int] = Nil,
    …
) extends Something {…}
```

Do i really need to explicitly repeat all parameters *with the additional keywords `override val` on top*‽

```
case class SomeHypothesis(
    anotherArg: SomeType,
    override val requirement: Boolean = false,
    override val onlyDays:   Seq[Int] = Nil,
    …
) extends Hypothesis(
    requirement,
    onlyDays,
    …
) {…}
```

Or is there a syntax like

```
case class SomeHypothesis(anotherArg: SomeType, **) extends Hypothesis(**) {…}
```

I don’t even need `anotherArg`, just a way to pass all keyword args to the super constructor.

---

I really like Scala’s idea about constructors, but if there isn’t a syntax for that one, I’ll be disappoint :(

Comment: [Common Scala mistake: unnecessarily overriding vals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332574/common-programming-mistakes-for-scala-developers-to-avoid/6231394#6231394)

Comment: I’d downvote this comment if I could, since it is wrong. At least for me, this is not the case. See the first comment on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6497059/scala-inherit-parameterized-constructor#6497200). I guess you should try it with default parameters. (Or my compiler does different things than yours, but I doubt that.)

Comment: It has nothing to do with default parameters, but you're right: you do need `override` in this situation.  Since you're using a case class, all of the constructor parameters implicitly have the `val` modifier. Because of the name clash, you have to add an explicit `override` modifier (and also an explicit `val` modifier, for the parser's happiness). My apologies for the hasty comment.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can just use a dummy name in the inherited class:

```
case class SomeHypothesis(anotherArg: SomeType, rq: Boolean = false, odays: Seq[Int] = Nil)
extends Hypothesis(rq, odays)
```

but you do have to repeat the default values. There is no need to override a `val`.

EDIT:

Note that your abstract class should not be a case class. Extending case classes is now [deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002725/which-things-around-case-classes-will-be-removed-after-scala-2-9-exactly). You should use an [extractor](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/112) for you abstract class instead:

```
abstract class SomeHypothesis(val request: Boolean)

object SomeHypothesis {
  def unapply(o: Any): Option[Boolean] = o match {
    case sh: SomeHypothesis => Some(sh.request)
    case _ => None
  }
}
```

Comment: But Mr compiler disagrees: `overriding value requirement in class Hypothesis of type Boolean; value requirement needs \`override' modifier` (And when i add it, Mr compiler tells me that `'val' expected but identifier found.`)

Comment: ah, now I see what you mean: Using other names saves me from having to override stuff. But that’s only a minor annoyance to the fact that I still have to write everything again for all subclasses. Not DRY at all >:(

Comment: Sorry, I missed the point that you were using case classes. But - you're not supposed to have an abstract case class anyway - extending case classes is a deprecated feature.

Comment: What? Why? And what should I do instead?

Comment: A discussion on case classes inheritance deprecation: http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/scala-Do-you-use-case-class-inheritance-td2001640.html. You should use extractors: http://www.scala-lang.org/node/112

Answer (score 5):

In my mind the policy of default values doesn't belong in the base class but should go on the concrete classes. I'd instead do the following:

```
trait Hypothesis {
  def requirement: Boolean
  def onlyDays: Seq[Int]
  /* other common attributes as necessary */
}

case class SomeHypothesis(anotherArg: SomeType,
                          requirement: Boolean = false,
                          onlyDays: Seq[Int] = Nil)
  extends Hypothesis
```

The case class fields of `SomeHypothesis` will fulfill the requirements of the Hypothesis trait.

As others have said, you can still use an extractor for pattern matching on the common parts:

```
object Hypothesis {
  def unapply(h: Hypothesis): (Boolean, Seq[Int]) = (h.requirement, h.onlyDays)
}
```

Comment: My problem is still that I shouldn’t have to repeat myself. And I truly want to have a shared constructor interface that behaves the same in all subclasses. So every time I write `name: Type = default`, I’m repeating myself thrice. (should be 0)

Comment: Then maybe they shouldn't be different subclasses. Instead there is one hypothesis class parameterized by extra data. Perhaps something like `case class Hypothesis[T](info: T, requirement: Boolean = false, onlyDays: Seq[Int] = Nil)` but perhaps with a type bound on T to ensure some common interface.

Comment: sounds good. in fact, i need a *requirement*, an *expectation* and some *filters* (onlyDays, …). then i need to apply a *function* on the filtered data, which has to get grouped for some of these functions (the *grouping* criterion can be provided). then i need to evaluate the function result by an *expectation* (“in range 0 to 0.05”, “true”, “low”). the outcome of this evaluation can be used in requirements. (all parameters *emphasized*)

Answer (score 3):

I've spend DAYS bashing my head on the desk trying to understand why named params were not going into an extended class.

I tried traits, copy() you name it - me and the compiler were always at odds and when things did compile the values never got passed.

So to be clear if you have class

```
class A(someInt:Int = 0, someString: String ="xyz", someOtherString: String = "zyx")
```

And you want to extend it:

```
class B extends A // does NOT compile 

class B(someInt: Int, someString: String, someOtherString: String) extends A // compiles but does not work as expected
```

You would think that a call to B like so:

```
case object X = B(someInt=4, someString="Boo", someOtherString="Who")
```

Would in fact either NOT compile (sadly it does) or actually work (it does NOT)

Instead you need to create B as follows (yes this is a repeat of an above answer but it wasn't obvious at first when google led me here...)

```
class B(someInt: Int, someString: String, someOtherString: String) extends A(someInt, someString, someOtherString)
```

and now

```
case object X = B(someInt=4, someString="Boo", someOtherString="Who")
```

Both COMPILES and WORKS

I have not yet worked out all the combinations and permutations of what/when and where you can put default values in the class B constructor but I'm pretty sure that defaults can be specified in the definition of class B with "expected" results.

Answer (score 0):

If Hypothesis is an abstract class, then I'd not have a constructor for it. I'd
set those parameters as abstract attributes of the abstract class.

But then, in this case you do need the `override` modifier.

Comment: I need it anyway, see my comment to the other answer. Also, they are always the same and have always the same default values, so I wouldn’t save more than the two parentheses from the abstract class’s constructor. And I want to save all the duplication.