# How to mimic constructor arguments in a scala trait?

Tags: android, scala, inheritance, traits

I created a Trait to combine all common ViewHolder properties in one place.

```
trait MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
  def view: View = this.itemView
}
```

Then I wanted to use this trait in my classes like so:

```
case class MyItemHolder(override val view: View, items: Array[String]) extends MyHolder
```

Unfortunately it gives me an error.

```
Not enough arguments for constructor ViewHolder: (x$1: android.view.View)android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder.
[error] Unspecified value parameter x$1.
[error]   case class MyItemHolder(override val view: View, items: Array[String]) extends MyHolder
```

I can get it to compile with this class definition but it seems redundant.

```
case class MyItemHolder(override val view: View, items: Array[String]) extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) with MyHolder
```

How can I get rid of `RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view)`?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot drop the constructor of `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` because you have to tell Scala how to call the super constructor. In general you don't need to override the constructor parameter, but you can use any arbitrary value:

```
class BaseClass(val x: Int)
class SubClass1 extends BaseClass(3)
// or
class SubClass2(val y: Int) extends BaseClass(y)
// or
class SubClass3(override val x: Int) extends BaseClass(x)
```

As already mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6497059/scala-inherit-parameterized-constructor) `SubClass2` and `SubClass3` are equivalent.

One of the characteristics of a `trait` is, that it has no constructor (for keeping *single inheritance*).
Additionaly a `trait` that extends a `class` means that this `trait` can only be used in that class or a subclass of this:

```
class BaseClass
class OtherClass
trait T extends OtherClass
class OtherSubClass extends OtherClass

class SubClass1 extends BaseClass with T // error: illegal inheritance;
class SubClass2 extends T // okay*
class SubClass3 extends OtherSubClass with T // okay
```

*`SubClass2` only works because the primary constructor of `OtherClass` is empty. Otherwise you have to call the constructor explicitly as in the first code snippet.

Putting that together, there is no way of calling the constructor implicitly.